# Как я могу добавить классы?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть [код](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-khayyam-9trl6), который создаёт выпадающий список. Мне нужно добавить к каждой кнопке класс соответственно тому в каком массиве находится id этой кнопки. Т.е. к кнопкам из массива "A" и "B" нужно добавить класс "A" и "B", а к кнопки из массива "C" и "D" можно добавить общий класс.

```js
    const A = [
      { category: "Walls", id: "1", symbol: "Wall_102", family: "Basic Walls" },
      { category: "Walls", id: "2", symbol: "Wall-Ext_102", family: "Basic Walls" }
    ];
    const B = [
      {
        category: "Window",
        id: "3",
        symbol: "Window-Ext_102",
        family: "Basic Window"
      },
      {
        category: "Walls",
        id: "4",
        symbol: "Wall-Other-102",
        family: "Other Walls"
      }
    ];
    const C = [
      { category: "Walls", id: "5", symbol: "Wall-Ext_102", family: "Basic Walls" },
      { category: "Floor", id: "6", symbol: "Floor-Ext_102", family: "Basic Floor" }
    ];
    const D = [
      { category: "Walls", id: "5", symbol: "Wall-Ext_102", family: "Basic Walls" },
      { category: "Walls", id: "6", symbol: "Wall-Ext_102", family: "Basic Walls" }
    ];

    const data = [...A, ...B, ...C, ...D];

    const result = data.reduce(
      (acc, curr) => {
        const { category, family, symbol, id } = curr;
        acc.category[category] = acc.category[category] || { family: {} };
        acc.category[category].family[family] = acc.category[category].family[
          family
        ] || { symbol: {} };
        acc.category[category].family[family].symbol[symbol] = acc.category[
          category
        ].family[family].symbol[symbol] || { id: [] };
        acc.category[category].family[family].symbol[symbol].id.push(id);
        return acc;
      },
      { category: {} }
    );

    let html = "";

    for (let categoryKey in result.category) {
      html += `<details><summary>${categoryKey}</summary>`;

      for (let familyKey in result.category[categoryKey].family) {
        html += `<details><summary>${familyKey}</summary>`;

        for (let symbolKey in result.category[categoryKey].family[familyKey]
          .symbol) {
          let btn =
            result.category[categoryKey].family[familyKey].symbol[symbolKey];
          html += `<details><summary>${symbolKey}</summary>
            ${btn.id.map(id => `<button>${id}</button>`).join("")}
            </details>
            `;
        }
        html += `</details>`;
      }
      html += `</details>`;
    }

    document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: код лучше добавить в сам вопрос

Comment: Хорошо, добавлю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оставил комментарии там, где были изменения, остальное не трогал (надеюсь правильно понял задачу):

```js
const A = [
  { category: "Walls", id: "1", symbol: "Wall_102", family: "Basic Walls" },
  { category: "Walls", id: "2", symbol: "Wall-Ext_102", family: "Basic Walls" }
];
const B = [
  {
    category: "Window",
    id: "3",
    symbol: "Window-Ext_102",
    family: "Basic Window"
  },
  {
    category: "Walls",
    id: "4",
    symbol: "Wall-Other-102",
    family: "Other Walls"
  }
];
const C = [
  { category: "Walls", id: "5", symbol: "Wall-Ext_102", family: "Basic Walls" },
  { category: "Floor", id: "6", symbol: "Floor-Ext_102", family: "Basic Floor" }
];
const D = [
  { category: "Walls", id: "5", symbol: "Wall-Ext_102", family: "Basic Walls" },
  { category: "Walls", id: "6", symbol: "Wall-Ext_102", family: "Basic Walls" }
];

/* Добавляем каждому объекту название своего класса */
A.forEach( (e)=> {e.class = 'A'});
B.forEach( (e)=> {e.class = 'B'});
[...C, ...D].forEach( (e)=> {e.class = 'CD'});

const data = [...A, ...B, ...C, ...D];

const result = data.reduce(
  (acc, curr) => {
    const { category, family, symbol, id } = curr;
    acc.category[category] = acc.category[category] || { family: {} };
    acc.category[category].family[family] = acc.category[category].family[
      family
    ] || { symbol: {} };
    acc.category[category].family[family].symbol[symbol] = acc.category[
      category
    ].family[family].symbol[symbol] || { id: [] };
    acc.category[category].family[family].symbol[symbol].id.push(id);
    /* Рядом с id записываем и класс */
    acc.category[category].family[family].symbol[symbol].class = curr.class; 
    return acc;
  },
  { category: {} }
);

let html = "";

for (let categoryKey in result.category) {
  html += `<details><summary>${categoryKey}</summary>`;

  for (let familyKey in result.category[categoryKey].family) {
    html += `<details><summary>${familyKey}</summary>`;

    for (let symbolKey in result.category[categoryKey].family[familyKey]
      .symbol) {
      let btn =
        result.category[categoryKey].family[familyKey].symbol[symbolKey];
        html += `<details><summary>${symbolKey}</summary>
          <button class="${result.category[categoryKey].family[familyKey].symbol[symbolKey].class}">
          ${btn.id.map(id => `${id}</button>`).join("")}</details>`;
    /*Выше добавлен кусок для классов*/
    }
    html += `</details>`;
  }
  html += `</details>`;
}

document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

```css
details {margin-left: 15px;}
```

P.s. У вас там внутри `Wall-Ext_102` неправильная кнопка. Не ясно, по задумке там должна была быть одна, или 4.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. В `Wall-Ext_102` должно быть 4 кнопок, т.к. мы смотрим на то, где находится `id`, а у меня эти `id` находятся в категории-семье-символе=`Walls`-`Basic Walls`-`Wall-Ext_102`. А эти 4 кнопки должны иметь различные имя классов, т.к. они находятся в различных массивах.

Comment: В вашем коде кнопки из категории `Walls` - `Basic Walls` - `Wall-Ext_102` все имеют класс CD, хотя там есть кнопка с `id` 2, которая должна иметь класс `A`.

Comment: Я переформатировал ваш [код](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-platform-cldd0) и сейчас мне остаётся только отобразить это на странице.

Comment: Чисто для интереса даю [ссылку](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-cherry-t6pjo) на уже законченный код, вот так в конечном итоге должен выглядеть моя задача. Буду очень рад, если вы предложить улучшение или более хорошее решение.